# In C#, is it possible to get a hash from a byte array that is filename safe?

Tags: c#, hash, sha1

I have a need to hash the contents of a file (to get a unique value, based on the file contents), and then write a file to the file system, named for that hash.

Is this possible?  I did it using SHA1, but got characters in the resulting hash that were not file system safe (slashes, colons, etc.).

Comment: a hash is just a number; you can convert to whatever representation you like (such as MIME64 for example, or an encoding that doesn't have invalid path chars)

Comment: Also, the idea that using a hash will give you a unique value is flawed.  Hashes as are designed to have a low probability of collisions for a reasonable problem size, but that probability is not zero.  If you're doing more than a few of these, you need to be prepared for what happens when two inputs result in the same hash.

Comment: @Joel: SHA1 is 160 bits, isn't it? I'm pretty sure that means there is an infinitessimal chance of collision for any reasonable number of inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var originalBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
var hashedBytes = Hasher.ComputeHash(originalBytes);

var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Byte hashed in hashedBytes)
    builder.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", hashed);

return builder.ToString();
```

this is basically the equivalent of what git does

Comment: It was an instance that was injected, but could easily be replaced by any hash algorithm (sha1, md5, etc)

Comment: So, this is code to take a hash create by other means and make it file system safe correct?  Could the "cleaning" of it introduce potential collisions?  Could "cleaning" two different hashes cause them to result in the same final value?

Comment: no it can't. it takes each byte and and converts it to the base16 representation (0-F), so no data is lost.